# How to initiate multiple structs

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++.

Have a struct `Bbox` with a constructor with two arguments `x` and `y` which I have just added. Before when the constructor had no arguments I could initiate multiple instances of `Bbox` by doing this and `num_components` was the number of instances I wanted to create:

```
Bbox list [num_components];
```

But how can I do that now when the constructor require arguments?

```
struct Bbox {
    int
        left,
        top,
        right   = 0,
        bottom  = 0,
        mat_width,
        mat_height;
    
    Bbox(int x, int y):
        left(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()),
        top(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()),
        mat_width(x),
        mat_height(y)
    {}
};
```

The arguments to initiate the list of `Bbox` are always the same. Lets say `x=10` and `y=20` but don't want to add default values to the construtor because the values can vary

Comment: I realise that you need to clarify your question.  Do you want to make, say, 10 boxes all of the same size in a single call, or should each one be different?

Comment: @PaulSanders they are all the same as in your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And, to build on @anoop's (excellent) answer, if you use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of a C-style array (and you should!), then you can do this:

```
std::vector <Box> make_boxes (int num_boxes)
{
    return std::vector <Box> (num_boxes);
}
```

And you would call it thus:

```
auto my_boxes = make_boxes (10);
```

But `make_boxes` is so trivial that it's hardly worth factoring it out, really.

---

If you want `make_boxes` to construct boxes with a size specified by the caller, then this would do the job:

```
std::vector <Box> make_boxes (int num_boxes, int x, int y)
{
    std::vector <Box> boxes;
    boxes.reserve (num_boxes);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_boxes; ++i)
        boxes.emplace_back (x, y);

    return boxes;
}
```

and then:

```
auto boxes = make_boxes (10, 10, 20);
```

Comment: And how can I add the arguments `x` and `y` to the code?

Comment: I don't want to add a constructor with the default values because the arguments vary at each initiation

Answer (score 1):

Use curly-brackets to initialize the array:

```
Bbox list [num_components] = {
    // ...
};
```

Then for each `Bbox` object you need curly-braces again:

```
{ SOME_X, SOME_Y }
```

Combined it would be like:

```
Bbox list [num_components] = {
    { SOME_X, SOME_Y },
    // ...
    { SOME_OTHER_X, SOME_OTHER_Y }
};
```

If you want to be able to create default-constructed `Bbox` object, without any explicit initialization, you must create a `Bbox` default constructor.

---

Now remember that an array have a size that is fixed at the time of compilation. They also tend to decay to pointers when least wanted.

If you need a dynamic "array" whose size doesn't have to be known at compile-time, and where you can add or remove elements at run-time, you should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<Bbox> list;
```

You can initialize it just like for arrays, or add elements later when needed:

```
list.emplace_back(some_x, some_y);
```

As a vector is an "object", it's also easy to pass copies of it to function, or passing references if you have a lot of elements in it. It keeps track of its own size, you can easily [loop over](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) a vector, and use many of the nice [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) available in the standard library. Well you can do this with array, and even pointers, but it's easier with a vector.

Comment: I can have more than thousands of `Bbox` instances. I don't want to add a line per initiation. What is the difference between this and using a `vector`?

Comment: @clarkk A vector is *dynamic*. You can add elements when needed at run-time. Added a simple example on how to use a vector to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The arguments to initiate the list of Bbox are always the same. Lets say x=10 and y=20

You can add a default constructor that will [**delegate**](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overlapping-and-delegating-constructors/) the work to the parameterized constructor by passing the argument `10` and `20` as shown below:

```
struct Bbox{
//other parameterized constructor as before

//----------vvvvvvvvvvv------>delegate the work to parameterized ctor
    Bbox(): Bbox(10, 20) //this is a default ctor delegating the work to the other ctor
    {
    }
};

Bbox list[num_components]; //works now assuming num_components is a constant expression
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/jm_vRSDHt)

Comment: But I don't want to add default values to the construtor because the values will vary each time I do the initiation

Comment: @clarkk We've to provide the information(`x` and `y` in your case) so that it(that info) can be used to create objects of type `Bbox`. If you don't want to have default values(as they vary per initiation), how do you intend to pass that information? I mean is there any connection between to varying values and how they will be used inside the ctors. Using `std::vector` might help here as it a dynamic container and has `emplace_back` shown in other answers.